# Tabulator - Right click menu doesnt work 2nd time round

Tags: tabulator

I am using tabulator to build a table builder that my users can modify how the table looks(columns, pagination, data etc).

I have a right-click menu on the headers with options to edit the column title, or delete a column.

It all works fine and is how I want it the first time around.

When the user modifies how it looks, for example, changing from no pagination to pagination, I am destroying the table and rebuilding it... like this...

```
 this.element.empty();
 this.table.destroy();
 this.table = null;
 this.initTable();
```

Everything gets drawn right, with all the correct data, however I can no longer use the right click menu, it just does nothing and I get an error in the console..

```
tabulator.min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: e.action is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>
```

I am guessing the problem is something to do with event listeners? Am I destroying the table in the best way?

Any advice would be appreciated.

I am using tabulator v4.8.4 - I cannot go to v5 right now as it's a substantial change.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to upgrade to Tabulator 5.1 there were issues with the menu library in that version that did not properly clear out references to previous menus when the table was destroyed

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure that going to v5.1 is going to be possible due to it being such a large change in the fundamentals. If you have any guidance on where I may look to "hack" my 4.8 version I would appriciate it